# Matplot++ Linking issue

Tags: c++, matplotlib, linker-errors

I am trying to use matplot++ and I have installed it using homebrew and have included the header

```
#include <matplot/matplot.h>
```

In my command line I have added the argument

```
-I /usr/local/Cellar/matplotplusplus/1.1.0_1/include/
```

in order to try to have my compiler reach the header file. Somehow this is still causing the error of

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have looked into linking errors and set a PATH too but the compiler cannot find it.
I am using C++ VScode on a Mac. I used the homebrew getinfo method to find the path of my library. If there is another solution or anything I overlooked please let me know! Thank you

Comment: `-I` tells the compiler where to look for files specified by the `include` directive. `ld` is the linker, that happens after the compiler's done its work. You a re likely missing a `-L<path to library files>` and at least one `-l<library name>` if you're getting an error from the linker, but we need the full error message, not just the tail end of the diagnostics saying a linker error occurred, to help you figure out exactly what went wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have also tried replacing the -I with -L but that doesn't work before. I was missing the -l <library name>

Comment: Did you succeed with this way of linking, or did you finally go with `CMake`?

Answer (score 1):

Probably, it's a better option to use CMake to manage and build the `matplot++`.

If you have CMake `3.14+` installed, you could use `FetchContent` Command to automatically download the `metplot++` repository.

1. Check your `CMake` version

```bash
cmake --version
```

2. Include `FetchContent` in your CMake build script:

```bash
include(FetchContent)
```

3. Declare the source for the contents:

```bash
FetchContent_Declare(matplotplusplus
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/alandefreitas/matplotplusplus
        GIT_TAG origin/master) # or whatever tag you want
```

4. Let CMake download the repository and include it as a subdirectory.

```
FetchContent_GetProperties(matplotplusplus)
if(NOT matplotplusplus_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate(matplotplusplus)
    add_subdirectory(${matplotplusplus_SOURCE_DIR} ${matplotplusplus_BINARY_DIR} EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
endif()
```

5. When creating your executable, link the library to the targets you want:

```
add_executable(your_target main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(your_target PUBLIC matplot)
```

6. Then add this header to your source files:

```cpp
#include <matplot/matplot.h>
```

Check the [documentation](https://github.com/alandefreitas/matplotplusplus#embed-with-cpmcmake) for more details

Comment: The guide probably specifies `CMake` because it makes everything simple.  I struggled with linking the old way before finally gave in.  It's a good decision.